# ¿Como comparo caracteres en estos dos strings?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, cifrado

Tengo que descifrar un texto usando la ecuación **p = ax + b (mod 26)**

Con a, b ∈ {0, . . . , 25} los cuales son los valroes que quiero hallar para descifrar.
Y x es la posición del caracter cifrado en la tabla ASCII que son letras mayúsculas, ósea x va de 65 a 90.

Tengo este código, donde busco todos los posibles valores de a y de b, y los comparo con el texto cifrado a ver si la palabra cifrada está dentro del texto, pero tengo problemas al compararlo.

Un ejemplo:

texto: OXOGLQJIMOGXUEXUVORUBUURBMZUBOGLUUGIYHULQBU
palabra: ESTUDIO
con a = 5 y b = 7, funciona.

¿Cómo puedo recorrerlo bien?
El código usando el ejeplo que tengo me retorna a = 2 y b = 13 (debería de ser a=5 y b=7)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    

char texto[100], palabra[20];
int palabra_cifrada[100];
int i = 0, x, p, j, a, b, k = 0, contador = 0, contadorp = 0, tamanio, aux, aux1;


scanf("%s\n", &texto);
scanf("%s", &palabra);


while(texto[i] != '\0'){
    contador++;
    i++;
}
i = 0;


while(palabra[i] != '\0'){
    contadorp++;
    i++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < 26; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < contador; k++){
                palabra_cifrada[k] = (a*int(palabra[k])+b)% 26;
                aux = a*int(palabra[k])+b% 26+65;
                if (aux == texto[k]){
                a = i;
                b = j;  
            }
        }
    }
}

printf("%d %d", a, b);

printf("%d %d", a, b);

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estás en C++ ... usa C++:

- Reemplaza `texto` y `palabra` por `std::string`.
- Usa los mecanismos de I/O propios de C++
- Tabula correctamente el código
- Declara las variables únicamente cuando necesites utilizarlas
- Dale a las variables un nombre que aporte información acerca del sentido de la variable

El código ahora quedará algo más limpio:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string texto, palabra;
    std::cin >> texto >> palabra;

    size_t const long_texto = texto.length();

    int palabra_cifrada[100];
    
    int a, b;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < 26; j++){
            for(size_t k = 0; k < long_texto; k++){
                palabra_cifrada[k] = (a*int(palabra[k])+b)% 26;
                int aux = a*int(palabra[k])+b% 26+65;
                if (aux == texto[k]){
                    a = i;
                    b = j;  
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Con estos cambios ya hechos, fíjate ahora en los comentarios que te voy a poner:

```
int main(){
    std::string texto, palabra;
    std::cin >> texto >> palabra;

    size_t const long_texto = texto.length();

    int palabra_cifrada[100];
    
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < 26; j++){
            for(size_t k = 0; k < long_texto; k++){
                palabra_cifrada[k] = (a*int(palabra[k])+b)% 26;
                //                    ~                 ~ <<--- variables no inicializadas
                int aux = a*int(palabra[k])+b% 26+65;
                //        ~                 ~ <<--- variables no inicializadas

                if (aux == texto[k]){
                    a = i;
                    b = j;  
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Mientras no se cumpla que `aux == texto[k]`, tanto `a` como `b` permaneceran sin inicializar. Los resultados que se obtengan entonces no serán válidos.

Entiendo que para saber si la palabra se encuentra en el texto cifrado deberias:

- Iterar por los diferentes valores de A y B, y para cada combinación:

  - Recorrer la cadena cifrada y, para cada posición:

    - Comprobar si la palabra a buscar se encuentra en esa posición

Algo así:

```
int a, b;
bool fin = false;
for(a = 1; a < 26 && !fin; a++){
    for(b = 1; b < 26 && !fin; b++){
        // ciframos la palabra
        std::string palabra_cifrada = palabra;
        for(char & c : palabra_cifrada)
            c = 'A' + ((a * c + b) % 26);

        // comprobamos si la secuencia se encuentra en el texto
        for (size_t i=0; i<texto.length() - palabra_cifrada.length() && !fin; i++)
        {
            int compare = texto.compare(i, palabra_cifrada.length(), palabra_cifrada);
            fin = (compare == 0);
        }
    }
}

a--; b--;
std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
```

Se resta 1 a los valores de `a` y `b` por la forma de trabajar de los bucles `for`. Como el incremento se aplica antes de evaluar la condición, es necesario deshacer dicho incremento final